# Questions about BRST symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, yang-mills, brst

For a course about the standard model, I am writing a paper on BRST symmetry. For this I am mainly following the material developed in chapter 16.4 of Peskin and Schroeder. I am mostly done, however there are still two questions remaining that I cannot seem to answer.

1. On page 518, they write that the second BRST variation of the ghost field is given by 
   \begin{equation}
   Q^2 c^a = \frac{1}{2}g^2 f^{abc}f^{bde}c^cc^dc^e. \tag{16.49}
   \end{equation}
   I am able to prove this fact but then they claim that this vanishes due to the Jacobi identity for the structure constants $f^{abc}$. Here, I have tried to prove this but I can never show this. Does anybody have any hint how you would prove this?
2. On page 519 they introduce the conserved charge $Q$ associated to the BRST symmetry. On the same page they seem to use the fact that this operator is Hermitian. (To prove that states in $\mathcal{H}_2={\rm Im}(Q)$ have zero inner product with each other.) However, I see no reason why this operator should in fact be Hermitian. Can anyone enlighten me as to why this fact is true?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please only ask *one question per post* - only ask several if they are so closely related that it wouldn't make sense to split them up since they cannot reasonably be answered separately. That way, answerers that might be able to answer one question but not the others still can provide useful, complete answers to a question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nilpotency follows from the fact that $c^cc^dc^e$ is cyclic in the indices $c$, $d$ & $e$, so that we may replace the structure constants $ff$' in the formula for $Q^2$ with the full [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) divided by 3.
2. The Hermiticity of the BRST charge $Q$ is a first principle of BRST theory. In Yang-Mills theory, it basically follows from the Hermiticity (possibly anti-Hermiticity in some conventions) of the fundamental variables of the theory.