Why the Slavnov operator is self-adjoint?
In the context of BRST we can define the Slavnov operator $\Delta_{BRST}$ which generates BRST transformations. My lecture notes claim that $\Delta_{BRST}$ is self-adjoint, but I don't see why.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480835/2451
